# The index of the biggest number in a field

Tags: java

my code is supposed to find the biggest value in a field and return index of the number. If they are indexes with the same number, it should return the lower index of the pair (or group). However my code doesn't work when all of my numbers are negative. It always returns 0, which is the default value of bestIndex. Can you help me fix my code? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
int bestIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    bestIndex = field[i] > field[bestIndex] ? i : bestIndex;
}

return bestIndex;
```

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve], not just a snippet

Comment: Your code works just fine. Maybe you're misinterpreting something ?

Comment: I just found out the cause of my problem but I don't know how to fix it. "Empty" array indexes are filled with 0 and 0 will always be bigger than any negative number. How should I solve the issue?

Comment: I want to compare array filled with just negative numbers and find the index of the biggest number. I am creating an array with int[] array = new int[100];

Comment: @Jack: the code should still work with arrays that hold negative numbers. Again, please [edit] your question to improve it. Please check out the [help] and the [ask] to see what we need as well as the [mcve] link given above.

Comment: I wonder if you're calling this method too early, on an array filled with int's default value of 0

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, that's my problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: Call the method only *after* you've filled the array with appropriate values. When you call it matters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am calling it after, however not every index of my array is filled, so some are "empty". However the empty indexes have value 0 so my method always returns 0. How do I fix it?

Comment: Is there a possibility that some of the filled indexes will be zero?

Comment: yes, some filled indexes might be 0.

Comment: Are the indexes that are filled contiguous, starting with index 0?

Comment: In my code, every index is starting with 0. However, I do not need to track values of indexed that have not been filled. I don't need those indexes at all.

Comment: Use an array of `Integer` so "unused" indexes will bue `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your comments you say:

> [0,0,0,-5,-4,-2,-1]. I would want my code to return -1, but my code
>   always returns 0

Finally you reveal what you really want.  
You don't want the index of the bigger item of the array but **the bigger item** itself, only **among the negative items**! 
 But the code you presented returns the index of the bigger item.  
So change to this (I'm using your code logic):

```
int greater = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    if (field[i] < 0)
        greater = field[i] > greater ? field[i] : greater;
}
return greater;
```

If there is **at least 1 negative number**, then the bigger negative will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you have an `Array` of 100 elements, and you have only filled some of them. So when the part of the `Array` that is filled is all negative, your method will return `0`, which is the default value of the unfilled indexes. What I would do is have a counter to keep track of how many indexes you have filled. Then when you call the method you can either pass the counter and loop until the counter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{   
    bestIndex = field[i] > field[bestIndex] ? i : bestIndex;
}
```

Or you could use `Arrays.copyOf()` to pass it as:

```
biggestIndex(Arrays.copyOf(field, count));
```

Which will pass a copy of the original `Array` truncated to only the amount of elements you have filled, so that if you have the `Array`:

```
[-1, -4, -34, -7, -39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....]
```

The count would be `5`, and you would only pass in a copy of length `5`, or the `Array`:

```
[-1, -4, -34, -7, -39]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked that the array is not empty or null and to set the `bestIndex=0` before executing the for loop, the code should be ok.

Also I suggest you to put the parenthesis on the boolean expression `(field[i] > field[bestIndex])` and it could be better to pass the array to a method that is returning you the `bestIndex`.

Anyway if you want an alternative I suggest you to do something like that:

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < field.length; i++ ){
      if ( field[i] > field[bestIndex] ) bestIndex = i;
  }
  return bestIndex;
```

Comment: Some of my indexes in my array are not filled with any value, so they stay at 0. So my code always return 0, since my values are always negative.

Comment: Can you share an array example?

Comment: [0,0,0,-5,-4,-2,-1]. I would want my code to return -1, but my code always returns 0. First 3 indexes have not been filled, they are at their default value.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your problem, I think that with negative indexes you will have more problems in the next development. Anyway in the for loop set i = -50000 ( Or a big escape negative value) and then add the if(field[i]=0) before the other if.

Comment: `"Also I suggest you to put the parenthesis on the boolean expression"` -- why? How will this possibly help solve his problem?

Comment: Sorry, it's just a suggestion.